# How do you create an isolate scope for a directive using AngularJS and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I'm just starting out writing directives using the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and some examples I have lying around. I'm trying to pass values into my directive with attributes but it's not working. Most of the difficulty is from trying to write this correctly using TypeScript syntax.

The index should show the text "Agatha" based on the customer variable passed to it, but for some reason it's not showing up.

Here's my simplified code:

**index.html**

```
<div>
    <user-display customer="agatha"></user-display>
</div>
```

**user-display.directive.html**

```
<div>
    <b>Name:</b> {{customer.name}}
</div>
```

**assign-users.directive.ts**

```
import { Main } from "../../main";
import * as angular from "angular";

export class UserDisplayDirective implements ng.IDirective {

    static $inject = [];
    restrict = "E";
    template = require("./user-display.directive.html");

    scope = {
        value: '=',
        customer: '='
    };

    constructor() { }

    link($scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: any) {
        $scope.agatha = {name: "Agatha"};
        $scope.ida = {name: "Ida"};
    }
}

class DirectiveFactory {
    public static GetFactoryFor<T extends ng.IDirective>(classType: Function): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        let factory = (args: any[]): T => {
            let directive = <any>classType;
            return new directive(args);
        };
        factory.$inject = classType.$inject;
        return factory;
    }
}

Main.module.directive("userDisplay", DirectiveFactory.GetFactoryFor<UserDisplayDirective>(UserDisplayDirective));
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a [`component`](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/) instead of a directive? That is exactly what components were made for

Comment: Mainly because I'm trying to learn how to write a directive but a component might be better. My end goal is to create a customized button dropdown and it might be messy trying to nest as a component but I'm not sure. Still, this is a simple and powerful thing to do with directives that I'd like to figure out.

Comment: In my experience, writing element directives as components since AngularJS 1.5 has been so much easier. General rule of thumb these days is if it's a directive for an attribute, make it a directive. If it's a directive for an element, make it a component. This also falls in line with the Angular guidelines if you were to ever upgrade

Comment: Will keep this practice in mind, thanks!

Comment: No problem =) Let me know if you need help with any of the component stuff. Todd Motto's article (which I linked above) is an excellent resource - but you may still have questions.

Comment: Use attribute `@` binding to bind the text of an attribute to scope. Avoid two-way `=` binding. Use one `<` binding for inputs; expression `&` binding for outputs.